# Heroku Rails Precompile errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, mixpanel

My Rails app is currently broken and when I check the heroku logs, I get the following:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (mixpanel.js isn't precompiled):
2013-07-22T21:05:04.591703+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2368959071303779648_52715720'
2013-07-22T21:05:04.587459+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 67ms
```

I've run `rake assets:clean` and `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` as Heroku's docs instructed me to do.

My `manifest.yml` looks like this:

---

```
first.jpeg: first-4ac2f941b0baf7a92561c83f3c1f74a1.jpeg
first/index.jpeg: first-4ac2f941b0baf7a92561c83f3c1f74a1.jpeg
second.jpeg: second-3e53e9e8f0968d1ec4611dc26f5a6c24.jpeg
second/index.jpeg: second-3e53e9e8f0968d1ec4611dc26f5a6c24.jpeg
twitter-login-button.png: twitter-login-button-6cfce5ace5f0a7831b13bb42281ef40a.png
twitter-login-button/index.png: twitter-login-button-6cfce5ace5f0a7831b13bb42281ef40a.png
application.js: application-74466be8c91632da68d8b2d6418aeb1c.js
application/index.js: application-74466be8c91632da68d8b2d6418aeb1c.js
application.css: application-d71cbf890e592c3a75ec56da2585da45.css
application/index.css: application-d71cbf890e592c3a75ec56da2585da45.css
jquery.min.map: jquery.min-6c267bfd2b3f36e6edccb2e584934c1c.map
jquery/index.min.map: jquery.min-6c267bfd2b3f36e6edccb2e584934c1c.map
```

And my `app/assets/javascripts` file has the following files:

- application.js
- mixpanel.js (the one that isn't precompiling)
- ga.js (google analytics)
- landings.js.coffee
- firebase.js

Finally, my `application.js` manfiest has this inside:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem? All of the documentation I found has not been helpful thus far. I'm guessing it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `config.assets.compile = false` in your `config/environments/production.rb`?  I had the same problem and switching it to `true` fixed this issue.

**confi/environments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = true
```